# Boost Voltage and Current in a Circuit

Tags: voltage, current, integrated-circuit

I am new to electronics and am trying to create a basic circuit that needs a 5V 3A output.  The input will be between 3.4V-4.8V and the current will be around 1-2A.  I've been looking around and I can't find an IC or anything that explains how to boost voltage and current in a circuit.  I'm wondering if anybody can help explain what I need to do to get my desired output or point me somewhere that can help me.

-Ben

Comment: What duty cycle do you need? If power out ((5 * 3) * duty cycle) watts is greater than power in (e.g. 3.4 * 1) you're out of luck.

Comment: You can use your input power to rev up a flywheel, then activate a generator for a short time to deliver higher output power than your input.   You won't succeed in delivering higher sustained output power, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only in electronics, but in physics, chemistry, biology and thermodynamics (to name a few), energy is conserved. That is, you cannot make a device or process which will take in a certain amount of energy and produce more than that. There are a few, specialized exceptions, such as nuclear reactions, but these can be handled properly.

In electronics, power is current times voltage. You have not specified your output waveform, but I assume you want a constant voltage and current out. If this is so, then your input (4.8 volts times 2 amps, or 9.6 watts) is less than your desired output (5 volts times 3 amps, or 15 watts). Therefore, what you want is simply impossible, which explains why you haven't had much luck. Note that, if you could do it, you would have a perpetual motion machine, and you would become fabulously wealthy and the recipient of the Nobel Prize. Maybe even more than one.

If, on the other hand, you only want to provide your 5 volts and 3 amps for brief periods of time, it is certainly possible to use an intermediate energy storage device such as a battery. In this case, your input would charge the battery more or less continuously, and the battery would be connected to a DC-DC converter to provide 5 volts/3 amps intermittently.